# MySQL select distinct user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like so...

```
id | user_id | account_id
-------------------------- 
1  | UserA   | Account1
1  | UserA   | Account2
1  | UserA   | Account1
1  | UserB   | Account1
1  | UserC   | Account1
```

I want to query and select all distinct users but if the user has a different account then it needs to be considered another distinct record.

The final out put of the query should be:

```
UserA - Account1
UserA - Account2
UserB - Account1
UserC - Account1
```

Here's my current query, just not sure how to make it do what I am wanting...

```
SELECT      distinct(t.user_id) as uId, t.account_id
FROM        Table t
```

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that all the ids are '1'

Comment: Your query is fine, but note that DISTINCT is not a function; it takes no arguments

Answer (score 1):

SELECT   DISTINCT  t.user_id as uId, t.account_id
FROM        Table t

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is not a function. It is applied to all the selected columns. It selects all the unique combinations of the resulting column values.

Try this:

```
select distinct user_id as uId, account_id
from Table t
order by uId, account_id;
```

Comment: Note that while quite correct, this is functionally identical to the OP's own answer, which is odd

Comment: @Strawberry - Quite right. I wonder what problem OP had with his/her query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT   distinct t.user_id , t.account_id
FROM Table t.

In this case distinct applied the both of the columns that is 'user_id' and 'account_id'

Comment: ...just as it does in the OP's example- which, admittedly, begs an obvious question, but there we are.

Answer (score -1):

This query may help

```
SELECT      t.user_id as uId, t.account_id FROM Table t 
           GROUP BY uId,account_id;
```

Check here [SQL FiDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e951ed/1)